# Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ is a monotonically increasing function then for all $a$, $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is an interval.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ be a monotonically increasing function. I need to prove that for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is an interval. I argued as follows.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x)>a$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $f(x)\leq a$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In the former case either $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ has an infimum or NOT; if it has an infimum $\lambda$ then $\{x:f(x)>a\}=(\lambda,\infty]$ or $[\lambda,\infty]$; if NOT then $\{x:f(x)>a\}=(\infty,\infty)$. In the latter case $\{x:f(x)>a\}=\emptyset$. So $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is an interval.

But I am not sure if the above argument is correct. However I initially tried proving the set $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is connected by showing any continuous function $$g:\{x:f(x)>a\}\to\{0,1\}$$

is constant where $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with its discrete topology, and I failed. Could someone please check the above proof and help me prove the result using the latter method as well? Thanks.

Comment: The infimum gives you a guess for the form of the interval, but you still need to prove that all the points in $(\lambda,+\infty)$ etc are part of $\{x:\ f(x)>a\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy* commented, you strictly only showed that teh set is contained in a certain interval.
Also, I personally find the long sequence of if-nots confusing.
Instead I'd go like this: Let $S=\{x:f(x)>a\,\}$. If $S=\Bbb R$ or $S=\emptyset$, we are done. Hence we may assume that $S\ne \emptyset$ and there exists $x_0$ with $x_0\notin S$. Then $x_0$ is a lower bound for $S$: If $x<x_0$ then $f(x)\le f(x_0)\le a$. Hence $\lambda:=\inf S$ exists. This implies $S\subseteq [\lambda,\infty)$.
If $x>\lambda$, then there exists $y\in S$ with $\lambda<y<x$, hence $f(x)\ge f(y)>a$, i.e., $x\in S$. So $(\lambda,\infty)\subseteq S$. 
We conclude that $S=(\lambda,\infty)$ or $S=[\lambda,\infty)$, depending on whether $\lambda\in S$ or not.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $A=\{x:f(x)>a\}$. Then $A=\emptyset$ or $A \ne \emptyset$. In the latest case, let's notice that if $x_1 \in A$ then  $\forall x \ge x_1$ it follows that $x \in A$, therefore $A$ is connected. The only connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Take $x,y\in{\{x:f(x)>a\}}$, and $z\in[x,y]$. We have to show that $z\in{\{x:f(x)>a\}}$. But $x<z$ and $f(x)>a$, since $f$ is increasing, we have $f(z)>a$.

Comment: What I need to show is that $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is an interval.